# Where is the eeprom in Thinkpad r52 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, bios, thinkpad, eeprom

At first, I was trying to remove the forgotten bios password (supervisor / administrator) by the trick given [in this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=exaXY92JXkw).

It is a Thinkpad R52, below are pictures of the motherboard:

[image: Thinkpad R52 motherboard]

So, This is the EEPROM:

[image: EEPROM]

(in a circle), please correct me if i am at wrong and also tell me which sides should be shot for the access.

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t do this. There is a very high chance it will totally brick the notebook.

Comment: Well, i had already shot top right and bottom left two pins but not working, maybe my timings are not correct, fortunately motherboard is still working so i think its safe to shot those pins but my concern is that, is it really eeprom or not

Comment: if it doesn't work, it's not right. And you've been warned.